# Calculation and replacement in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like the following and I need to compare the value of each year (2005-2009) with the average value of (2002-2004).

```
Year   Firm    R    
2002   A       30    
2003   A       11    
2004   A       1     
2005   A       7     
2006   A       15    
2007   A       20    
2008   A       3.5   
2009   A       8     
2002   B       24    
2003   B       30    
2004   B       25    
2005   B       5.2   
2006   B       11.8  
2007   B       78    
2008   B       90    
2009   B       57
```

The Issue that I need to calculate the average of (2002-2004) for each firm and replace the value in years 2002-2004 with the new value (i.e. the calculated average). for example, the new dataset should be like this:

```
 Year   Firm    R    
    2002   A       14    
    2003   A       14    
    2004   A       14     
    2005   A       7     
    2006   A       15    
    2007   A       20    
    2008   A       3.5   
    2009   A       8     
    2002   B       26.333    
    2003   B       26.333    
    2004   B       26.333    
    2005   B       5.2   
    2006   B       11.8  
    2007   B       78    
    2008   B       90    
    2009   B       57
```

I have tried to use the following code:

```
df$R[df$Year==2002 & df$Year==2003 & df$Year==2004] = (df$R[df$Year==2002] + df$R[df$Year==2003] + df$R[df$Year==2004])/3
```

but when I apply it nothing changes!!!!!?????
I hope you can help with this issue

Comment: The mistake in your code is that you are not grouping by `Firm` name and also using `&` instead or `|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table` for this if you like:

```
library(data.table)

year <- c(rep(seq(2002,2009,1),2))
firm <- c(rep("A",8),rep("B",8))
r <- c(30,11,1,7,15,20,3.5,8,24,30,25,5.2,11.8,78,90,57)

aa <- data.table(year,firm,r)

aa[year>=2002 & year<=2004, r:= mean(r), by = firm]
```

Giving this result :

```
    year firm        r
 1: 2002    A 14.00000
 2: 2003    A 14.00000
 3: 2004    A 14.00000
 4: 2005    A  7.00000
 5: 2006    A 15.00000
 6: 2007    A 20.00000
 7: 2008    A  3.50000
 8: 2009    A  8.00000
 9: 2002    B 26.33333
10: 2003    B 26.33333
11: 2004    B 26.33333
12: 2005    B  5.20000
13: 2006    B 11.80000
14: 2007    B 78.00000
15: 2008    B 90.00000
16: 2009    B 57.00000
```

Comment: when I apply your code I receive the following error: `Error in [.tbl_df (test2, year >= 2002 & year <= 2004, :=(r, mean(r)),  : 
  unused argument (by = firm)`

Comment: Have you installed the data table package?

Comment: yes I did. when I apply your code to a large dataset I receive this error. Does the class of the variable affect the code?? for example, `firm` and `year` are classified as `Factor`

Comment: Because the error says: `unused argument (by = firm)` makes me think your data set is a data.frame and not a data.table. Just to be certain assign your data to a variable using `test <- data.table(your data)`. Should not matter if firm is a factor but I would make year numeric.

Comment: then run `test[year>=2002 & year<=2004, r:= mean(r), by = firm]`

Comment: the problem solved. Thank you for your help. the code worked correctly but I should change year to numeric first.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake in your code is that you are not grouping by `Firm` name and also using `&` instead or `|`. In my example `test.txt` is the file which has input same as in question.

Below code should help you achieve what you need.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.delim('test.txt', header = T, sep = '\t')

print(df)

# get unique firm names for grouping
firms <- unique(df$Firm)

# for each firm, calculate mean and update it    
for (f in firms){
    df$R[df$Firm == f & (df$Year==2002 | df$Year==2003 | df$Year==2004)] = 
      sum(df$R[df$Firm == f & (df$Year==2002 | df$Year==2003 | df$Year==2004)])/3
}

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this dplyr version:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
    filter(Year<2005) %>% # this subsets the data
    group_by(Firm) %>% # state which values you want to evaluate
    summarise(m=mean(R)) %>% # take the mean (named mean)
    left_join(data) %>% # join the original data to the summarised data
    mutate(R=ifelse(Year<2005 & Firm=='A', m,
                ifelse(Year<2005 & Firm=='B', m, R))) %>% # nested ifelse to define conditions
    select(year,firm,R) -> newdata # select the desired columns and rename the data.frame
```